# Error: package or namespace load failed for �shiny�: When Deploying Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to deploy a shiny app onto shinyapps.io but I get the following output in Deploy tab:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for �shiny�:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'shiny', details:
  call: .Call("_httpuv_getRNGState", PACKAGE = "httpuv")
  error: "_httpuv_getRNGState" not available for .Call() for package "httpuv"
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

The app I am trying to deploy is the template/draft app you get when you start a new shiny web app file from RStudio. At first I thought the cause of the error might be something in my original apps that I tried to upload.

Would anyone be able to assist in fixing or at least explaining what might be causing the error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation points to just leave a comment, but if you search Google for your error lots of information comes up (i.e. [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2030) or [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2048)). It appears to be either an error with the install of httpuv or one of the packages it is linked to (such as Rcpp or later), so update those packages and see if that works.

Comment: First, Apologies, I didn't mention the research I'd done before hand. Had read the first post you suggested but not the second. Managed to fix the issue by re-installing the Rcpp package. Thank you for the useful info.